# Un-clickable link in new Profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

The new user-profile page has a "Next tag badge" element on it. For me, this is a "git" badge, and quite reasonably the badge itself is a link to a listing of unanswered git questions: the element looks like `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=unanswered">git</a>`, and if I right-click and Open in New Tab, I get taken to the place I expect. However, if I just click on the element normally, I don't go anywhere: instead, a tooltip appears, describing the "Bronze git tag badge" for me.

Conceivably this could be intended behavior, but I imagine the intent of the `<a>` element was to be a clickable link, and there's just some misconfigured onclick listener that's making it not work, so I think this is a bug report. For what it's worth I'm using Chrome 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.10.1; I've also reproduced it in Firefox 33.0 on Linux Mint 17.1.

Comment: And no "go get it"?

Comment: Ah, I see. A bug!

Comment: I've implemented what @nicael suggested - it will go live in a few minutes.  Thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it is a bug or by design, it would be better to add "go get it" button with a link mentioned by @ammaloy, like it is done for some badges in the main badge changer:

> [image]

Proposed for tag badges:

> [image]

Comment: Good idea; next build will add the "Go get it" call-to-action button, but **only on your own profile**.  This is consistent with the other call-to-actions.